# Definition of Hodge star operator

Tags: complex-geometry

When I read Griffths and Harris, the Hodge star operator is an operator form $A^{p,q}(M)$ to $A^{n-p,n-q}(M)$. But in Huybrechts' book it is from $A^{p,q}(M)$ to $A^{n-q,n-p}(M)$, because it takes conjugate before wedge product.

So which definition is more standard? Why does there exist two different definitions? I am really confused by this, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some define the Hodge star operator by $\langle \alpha, \beta\rangle\operatorname{vol} = \alpha\wedge\ast\beta$, in which case $\ast : A^{p,q}(M) \to A^{n-p,n-q}(M)$.

Other people instead define the Hodge star operator by $\langle \alpha, \beta\rangle\operatorname{vol} = \alpha\wedge\overline{\ast\beta}$ or $\langle\alpha, \beta\rangle \operatorname{vol} = \alpha\wedge\ast\bar{\beta}$, in which case $\ast : A^{p,q}(M) \to A^{n-q,n-p}(M)$.

The fact that there are different conventions is not deep, it is just a matter of preference.

In my experience, $\langle\alpha, \beta\rangle\operatorname{vol} = \alpha\wedge\overline{\ast\beta}$ is more common.